# Short hikes and views between Las Vegas and Salt Lake city

Tags: usa, utah, nevada

I will be spending a day driving between Las Vegas and Salt Lake city.

I find myself completely enthralled by the red cliffs and canyons of Utah.

I was wondering if anyone could recommend any stop along the way that my afford me some nice archetypal Utah vistas.

At most I could afford it to be a 4 hour detour from I15 highway. So if the location was 1.5 hours off course 1 way, I could hike for 1 hour total.

Two locations that I have already identified as good match for my criteria are Kolob Canyon and Red Cliffs trail.

Comment: This is far too broad -- Las Vegas to SLC is more than 400 miles. It's also opinion-based and against our "we're not travel agents or tour guides" policy.

Comment: You would be a whole lot cooler if you were....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two other excellent locations on they way are [Zion National Park](https://www.nps.gov/zion/index.htm) and [Bryce Canyon National Park](https://www.nps.gov/brca/index.htm). They're both a side trip from I15, and both have different but excellent scenery. Doing them both in a single day would probably be too much (unless you start very early), so if you can afford an extra day it would probably be worth it.